# Difference between Very sleepy and Callgrind for C++ profiling

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind, callgrind, verysleepy

I am trying to learn the difference between [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy) and [Callgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) for profiling. The code that I intend to profile is written in C++ and works under both Linux and Windows.

On Linux, I was able to use Callgrind to look at the Self and inclusive relative costs. From what I understand, Callgrind uses instrumented profiling technique and takes considerable time. However, Very Sleepy uses statistical profiling and is very quick. Since both uses different approaches to profiling, I cannot compare the results from the two.

Is there a way that I can do some sort of profile comparison on both Linux and Windows? Unfortunately, Callgrind is unavailable for Windows and vice versa for Very Sleepy.

Answer (score 2):

No. Such a comparison is between two unlike things. Use sampling when to get accurate profiling you cannot afford overhead. Use instrumentation when you need to understand control flow over time.

Answer (score 0):

Although, I couldn't get the answer for the first question. I have found a new tool that works on both Windows and Linux for C++ code profiling. Its called as CodeXL from AMD and its free.

http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/codexl/

Bonus if you have AMD processors or Catalyst graphics processors as some of the other capabilities of the tool becomes available.